# Firebase Spark plan - hosting - daily or monthly data transfer limits?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, quota

According to https://firebase.google.com/pricing the hosting data transfer limit is 360 MB/day.
In the firebase console, usage statistics for hosting/downloads are shown as percentage of 10GB/month.

From firebase FAQ, https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#pricing-blaze-free, "How is the free usage in the Blaze plan different from the free usage in the Spark plan?" --> "Free usage on the Blaze plan is calculated daily. [...]".

Like mentioned here, https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/zEgCSA5-Zkc, the daily quota is used for the Blaze plan.

Is my assumption correct that within the Spark plan, data transfers (downloads) up to 10GB/month are possible without enforced daily limits (which would make the app temporarily unavailable)?
Subsequently, there is no need to upgrade to Blaze plan just because of the hosting limits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The free quota for Firebase Quota is 360 MB / day. If you are on spark plan then your website won't be served on exceeding the quota. But if you are on Blaze plan, you still have the 360 MB / day free quota and you'll be charged only for the surplus usage over that quota.

For example if your usage was 900 MB for the day, you'll be charged for (900 - 360) = 540 MB of usage.

[image]

You'll see something like this on exceeding the 360 MB bandwidth for that day. To resume serving your site, you must upgrade to Blaze Plan.

I had a similar query long back and this is what Firebase Support said:

> Firebase Hosting provides 10 GB of downloads in the free plan, if the
> consumption for a website is more than that, the Blaze plan should be
> used.
>
> In your case, you/re on the Blaze plan, and you get those 10 GB/month
> (distributed in 360 MB/day) free of charge. Once the downloads go over
> the limit, you'll get charged for the exceeded amount.
>
> You only get charged for what your website offers. If you embed
> resources from third parties, the browser makes requests to those
> sites instead of your Firebase website.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the information. I find the firebase FAQ a bit confusing because stating that "Blaze and Spark free usage is different" and "Blaze is calculated daily" kind of implies that Spark is calculated in a different way.

Comment: No, the free quota remains same for both. If your issue was resolved, please click the tick icon on answer so others know that this is resolved. Else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Hello. I am trying to assess how much my bill will be if I utilize the Firebase hosting service, but I am not sure how to go about it. If the data transfer limit is 360mb/day, and the average web page is 3.4mb, then a website can only receive 105 hits/day to be in the free tier? This seems absurdly low compared to the generous free tiers of the other Firebase services and suspect that I am going about this incorrectly.

Comment: @christofuy Ideally you won't store large images in hosting. What's the breakdown of the 3.4 mb?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I haven't profiled my own web pages and used the 3.4 mb from this  [blog](https://speedcurve.com/blog/web-performance-page-bloat/) that was discussing average web page sizes, which I now realize says 3 mb not 3.4 mb. Nonetheless, thanks for the advice, and I'll have to look into caching and using Firebase storage for storing media content.